# How to convert JSON data from R to not be in one line

Tags: r

I extracted data in R using the twitteR package and searchtwitter. I am then converting to a JSON file. It works, but when I view the JSON in notepad++ it is one long string. Is there a way to get it to separate so that each tweet with its specific information is separate.

```
testreal <- searchTwitteR('startup', n = 100, lang = 'en')
testrealdf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(testreal, as.data.frame))
write(exportJson, file = "testrealdf.json")
json_realdf <- fromJSON(file="testrealdf.json")
```

My file in notepad looks like.....

[image]

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a JSON formatting plugin for notepad.  I would check out JSONviewer.

Comment: so this doesnt matter for analyzing my data in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonlite::toJSON(x=yourDataFrame, pretty=TRUE)`.  From `?toJSON`:

> `pretty`   adds indentation whitespace to JSON output. Can be TRUE/FALSE
>   or a number specifying the number of spaces to indent. See `prettify`

This is just for cosmetics.  The whitespace in JSON is not syntactically meaningful.  For a serialization format with syntactically meaningful whitespace, check out R's `yaml` package, which can also read JSON.